# How to extend a RichTextbox coloring function to color parts of strings?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void ColorRichTextbox(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
{
    int length = MyRichTextBox.TextLength;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyRichTextBox.Text))
    {
        MyRichTextBox.AppendText("\r\n" + text);
    }
    else
    {
        MyRichTextBox.AppendText(text);
    }
    MyRichTextBox.SelectionStart = length;
    MyRichTextBox.SelectionLength = text.Length;
    MyRichTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
}
```

Usage:

```
ColorRichTextbox(MyRichTextBox,
                    "This is example : " + DateTime.Now, Color.Red);
```

The result is one line in red consisting of "This is example : " with the `DateTime.Now` part. Is there a way to make for example the part "This is example : " in white color and `DateTime.Now` to be in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your method to not always force the text onto its own line, you could call it twice - first for white text and then for red:

```
private void ColorRichTextbox(RichTextBox box, string text, Color color, bool appendNewLine = true)
{
    int length = box.TextLength;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(box.Text) && appendNewLine)
    {
        box.AppendText("\r\n" + text);
    }
    else
    {
        box.AppendText(text);
    }
    box.SelectionStart = length;
    box.SelectionLength = text.Length;
    box.SelectionColor = color;
}
```

By setting `appendNewLine` to `false`, the entered text won't be put on a separate line, thus continuing where the previous call left off:

```
ColorRichTextbox(MyRichTextBox, "This is example : ", Color.White);
ColorRichTextbox(MyRichTextBox, DateTime.Now.ToString(), Color.Red, false); // false = Don't write this text on a separate line
```

---

**Side note:** You don't appear to be using the `box` argument of your method. If you want to use this for multiple RichTextBoxes, you should replace `MyRichTextBox` with `box` in your method (this has been done in my code above).

Result:

> [image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with a custom Interpolated String Handler.

```
richTextBox1.AppendColoredLine($"This is an example : {DateTime.Now:red}");
richTextBox1.AppendColoredLine($"This is an example : {DateTime.Now:green}");
richTextBox1.AppendColoredLine($"This is an example : {DateTime.Now:blue}");
richTextBox1.AppendColoredLine($"This is an example : {DateTime.Now:yellow}");

richTextBox1.AppendColoredLine($"Some other colored things: {"hi":orange}, {10:purple}, {this.Name:gray}");
```

[image: form screenshot]

Here's the code to make it work (needs .Net 6):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace;

public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    [InterpolatedStringHandler]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
    public ref struct ColoredStringHandler
    {
        private readonly RichTextBox textBox;
        private readonly IFormatProvider? formatProvider;

        public ColoredStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount, RichTextBox textBox, IFormatProvider? formatProvider = null)
        {
            this.textBox = textBox;
            this.formatProvider = formatProvider;

            textBox.DeselectAll();
        }

        public void AppendLiteral(string s) => textBox.AppendText(s);
        public void AppendFormatted<T>(T item) where T : notnull => AppendLiteral(item.ToString() ?? "");
        public void AppendFormatted<T>(T item, string format) where T : notnull
        {
            var color = Color.FromName(format);
            string? s = 
                item is IFormattable
                ? ((IFormattable)(object)item).ToString(null, formatProvider)
                : item.ToString();

            s ??= "";

            Color previousColor = textBox.SelectionColor;
            try
            {
                textBox.SelectionColor = color;
                textBox.AppendText(s);
            }
            finally
            {
                textBox.SelectionColor = previousColor;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AppendColored(this RichTextBox textBox, IFormatProvider? formatProvider,
        [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("textBox", "formatProvider")] ref ColoredStringHandler handler)
    {

    }

    public static void AppendColored(this RichTextBox textBox,
        [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("textBox")] ref ColoredStringHandler handler)
    {

    }

    public static void AppendColoredLine(this RichTextBox textBox, IFormatProvider? formatProvider,
        [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("textBox", "formatProvider")] ref ColoredStringHandler handler)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public static void AppendColoredLine(this RichTextBox textBox,
        [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("textBox")] ref ColoredStringHandler handler)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really neat! Didn't know this was possible. .NET 6 certainly has brought a lot of new, interesting features, and I've yet to dive into them.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah, they do make amazing features, I love C# more and more with each release. Can't wait for generic math in .Net 7